# Selecting from a subquery with the Doctrine query builder

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Suppose I have an `entries` table that looks something like this:

```
| id | category | text | user_id |
|----|----------|------|---------|
| 1  | A        | z    | 22      |
| 2  | B        | y    | 23      |
| 3  | B        | x    | 24      |
| 4  | C        | w    | 25      |
```

I want to get the row for specified category(ies) that have the highest ID.  So in this example if I'm search for category `B` I'd expect it to return `3,B,x,24`

There are several more columns in the table, but only those three are shown for brevity.  Other columns exist which have to be joined, e.g. to get user info.

I have the following query, which works:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
         SELECT MAX(id) as id
         FROM entries
         WHERE category = 'B'
         GROUP BY category
     ) as tmp
         LEFT JOIN entries e ON e.id = tmp.id
         LEFT JOIN users u ON (e.user_id = u.id)
```

I'm not sure how to transform this in to DQL, specifically using the query builder because there are several conditions to be added for which I do not want to build up a DQL string using concatenation.  I'm working with this:

```php
$subquery = $entityManager
    ->getRepository(Entry::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('entryIds')
    ->select('MAX(entryIds.id)'
    ->orWhere("entryIds.category = ?0")
    ->groupBy('entryIds.category')
    ->getDQL();

$rows = $entityManager
    ->getRepository(Entry::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('entry')
    ->select('entry, user')
    ->from("($subquery)", 'tmp')
    ->leftJoin(User::class, 'user', Join::WITH, 'entry.user = user.id')
    ->setParameter(0, 'B')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

And I get this error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 453 near ', (SELECT MAX(entryIds.id)': Error: Subquery is not supported here
```

The query builder generates this DQL from the above:

```sql
SELECT entry, user
FROM Namespace\\Entry entry
LEFT JOIN Namespace\\User user WITH entry.user = user.id,
(SELECT MAX(entryIds.id) FROM Namespace\\Entry entryIds WHERE entryIds.category = ?0 GROUP BY entryIds.category) tmp
```

So it looks like I'm not putting the subquery in the right place; where can I put it to ensure that the base select queries the subquery and then joins the other tables?

---

Edit: I managed to get it to work with WHERE ANY, but the query is 4.5 times slower:

```php
$subquery = $entityManager
    ->getRepository(Entry::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('entryIds')
    ->select('MAX(entryIds.id)')
    ->orWhere('entryIds.sourceSystem = ?0')
    ->groupBy('entryIds.sourceSystem, entryIds.secondaryId')
    ->getDQL();

$qb = $entityManager
    ->getRepository(Entry::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('entry');
$qb
    ->select('entry, user')
    ->leftJoin(User::class, 'user', Join::WITH, 'entry.user = user.id')
    ->setParameter(0, 'B')
    ->where(
        $qb->expr()->eq('entry.id', $qb->expr()->any($subquery))
    )
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```